# Android - How to send a table in email

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I want to send a table to a particular mail id via email, and I want to  retrieve the data from phpmysql as a table format

I am not getting any idea about sending table to mail. I have tried these links already, please could you send some different links:

- android - How to format the text as table in email body of email client
- Embed html table tag in email intent android - Stack Overflow
- How to send Html Table in Email in android Application - Stack Overflow
- Sending html email in android using , etc. - is there really no relatively built-in Intent way?

Comment: Pleas look thru current answer. It will help to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11448730/2685996

Comment: Thanks...How to send the table format???

Comment: use html table format. Kind of 
<html><head></head><body><table><tr><td></td></tr></table</html>
look trough http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm

Comment: But this table tag is not supporting in email

Comment: Sorry, it seems that now all e-mail clients are strict about HTML content. Try work around from answer, and please tell, will it work or not.

Answer (score 1):

try out below code:
Note : You can only send html as attachment (not as email content)

```
private void shareFile(String subject,String body,String fileContent) {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/html");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    File tempFile ;
    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File tempDir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/temp-sample");

        AppWebViewClient.deleteDirectoryFiles(tempDir); //delete temp files
        tempDir.mkdirs();
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("sample-records", ".html", tempDir);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        tempDir.setReadable(true, false);
        tempFile.setReadable(true, false);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        fout.write(fileContent.getBytes());
        fout.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append(body).toString()));
    // share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Records!"));
}
```

Comment: It's a fact to be honest because the other ones doesn't work. Thanks!